# Why is a tangent function being used to find horizontal length?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Problem: [image]
Why does the tangent function $175\tan(\theta)$ give us the horizontal length between either anchor 1 or 2 and the base? Doesn't tangent just give us the slope of the terminal ray, whereas sine and cosine gives us vertical and horizontal lengths? I don't understand why this solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Doesn't tangent just give us the slope of the terminal ray, whereas sine and cosine gives us vertical and horizontal lengths?

Actually, no. Observe the ratio.

$$\tan{\alpha}=\frac{opposite}{adjacent}$$

Note that the opposite side in this case is the horizontal distance while the adjacent distance is the length of the pole, 175ft. Hence, this becomes:
$$\tan{\alpha}=\frac{opposite}{175}$$

Therefore, $$opposite=175\tan{\alpha}$$